# How to write progress in cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I've created a function in Google Apps Script which downloads and renames the list files in Google Drive. I want to have their progress written in a particular cell. For example if first image has been downloaded and renamed in Drive so the text should be reflected in "PROGRESS" column with "COMPLETED" text.

Respectively the number of images will be downloaded and renamed, the text of "COMPLETED" should be reflected in the column next to their cells in a particular column called "PROGRESS", so if all of the images have been downloaded all of the cells under "PROGRESS" column should have "completed" in all of the columns.

Please help me as I have literally tried every thing but it is not getting done.

**below is the image elaboration what I want:
**

IMAGE ELABORATION
[image]

[GOOGLE SHEET URL]
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jItuI2tQbpH4A5b9CFS9xWV3mNtnrV2jMRYPxEZSvlM/edit?usp=sharing

[CODE]

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show alert', 'showAlert')
      .addToUi();
}

function showAlert() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.alert(
     'Please confirm',
     'Are you sure you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES){
    
    // User clicked "Yes".
    
   {
      let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

for (let i = 0; i < lastRow - 1; i++) {
let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder_id");
let url = sheet.getRange(2 + i, 1).getValue();
let image = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(url);
let blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
let name = sheet.getRange(2 + i, 2).getValue();
folder.createFile(blob).setName(name);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("task has been completed");


    }


  };
  
  } 
    
  else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('Permission denied.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Please update the question with only a single title.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can do that using Apps Script API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the confirmation to a position AFTER the loop. Something like this.

```
  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES){
    // User clicked "Yes".
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    for (let i = 0; i < lastRow - 1; i++) {
        let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder_id");
        let url = sheet.getRange(2 + i, 1).getValue();
        let image = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(url);
        let blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
        let name = sheet.getRange(2 + i, 2).getValue();
        folder.createFile(blob).setName(name);
        sheet.getRange(2+i,3).setValue("Completed")
        SpreadsheetApp.flush()    
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("task has been completed")
  } 
  else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('Permission denied.');
  }
```

Comment: It worked for the task completion stage but can you please help me out on displaying progress of each downloaded image on a separate column which is made for it. Is it possible to display "completed" on the column when the image has been downloaded?

Comment: Refer edited code: `sheet.getRange(2+i,3).setValue("Completed")`- inserts "Completed as each folder is processed. `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` updates the screen to show the "Completion" message.

Comment: thankyou so much tedinoz you helped me a lot

Comment: Is it Possible @Tedinoz that a music is being played after the completion of entire function with the completion message "your task has been completed"?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "played" - there's a bunch of precedents; google this: "google sheets script play music"